# Submit multipart/form-data using mechanize python?

Tags: python, post, http-headers, http-post, mechanize

I'm trying to make a POST request of multipart/form-data using mechanize, here's what it looks like from firefox live http header when I actually make a post:

```
http://example.com/new/example

POST /new/example HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://example.com/new/example
Cookie: tmgioct=c32MbAGn1sTuZrH8etPqVNU5; __qca=P0-495598852-1339139301054; __utma=189990958.911848588.1339139302.1339556345.1339561805.32; __utmz=189990958.1339139302.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); logged_in=1; tog_appearance_fieldset=fieldset_open; __utmc=189990958; pfu=42375294; pfp=h2YrFoaTr5LtrVys8PMmKNdyuoeA9FNLakxGzrJK; pfe=1371048319; __utmb=189990958.5.10.1339561805
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------41184676334
Content-Length: 2947
-----------------------------41184676334
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="UPLOAD_IDENTIFIER"

0ad3af1c502c7cb59577b01720ee58ff014810c4
-----------------------------41184676334
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="post[state]"

2
-----------------------------41184676334
blahblahblahblah....

-----------------------------41184676334--
```

And here's my code:

```
browser = mechanize.Browser()

url = "http://example.com/new/example"
header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0', 
    'Referer': 'http://example.com/new/example',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------41184676334'
}

data = "-----------------------------41184676334\rContent-Disposition: form-data; name="UPLOAD_IDENTIFIER"\r\r0ad3af1c502c7cb59577b01720ee58ff014810c4\r-----------------------------41184676334\rContent-Disposition: form-data; name="post[state]"\r\r2\r-----------------------------41184676334\rblahblahblahblah....\r\r-----------------------------41184676334--\r"

req = urllib2.Request(url, data, header)

response = browser.open(req, timeout = 30)
response.close()
```

I don't know why it does NOT work. Anybody knows? Please help me out.

By the way, does it have something to do with boundary? I use random numbers in above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using `requests` module to do the task. It turned out to be more convenient and reliable.

You can check out this page for details: [POST a Multipart-Encoded File](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)

Answer (score 1):

From the [MIME media types RFC 2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-4.1.1):

> The canonical form of any MIME "text" subtype MUST always represent a
> line break as a CRLF sequence.

Your code uses carriage returns ('\r') only; you need to add line feeds (`\n`) as well.

Comment: I've replaced all `\r` with `\r\n` and it still does NOT work, any other possible reason?

Comment: Define 'not work'. The website you are trying to spoof doesn't buy it? It could be that that site is looking for more than just the User-Agent and Referer headers to determine wether or not you use a 'real browser'.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. Does it have something to do with boundary number? I simply use a random generated number.

Comment: I doubt it. Perhaps the some of the cookies in the Cookie header are important too?

Comment: Tried almost everything with the header part, but still cannot find out why it's not working. Will have to use a real browser for the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.form.enctype = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```